# how to achieve tab switching restriction in next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, browser

I'm learning Next.js new right now. I'm working on a project of an online test system where I have to implement a logic that restricts the user from switching tabs. The first time the user clicks on a new tab, an alert should appear saying 'Tab switching not allowed.' And if the user clicks on a new tab again, then another alert should appear saying 'You are disqualified'. How can i achieve this in Next js, if you know please help me out

```
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const TestComponentWithTabDetection = () => {
  const [attemptCount, setAttemptCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleBeforeUnload = (e: any) => {
      // Increment attempt count
      setAttemptCount((currentCount) => currentCount + 1);
      // Check the number of attempts
      if (attemptCount === 0) {
        // First attempt: show a custom message and prevent tab switch
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
        alert("Don't switch your tab!"); // Show a warning message
      } else {
        // Second attempt: disqualify the session
        console.log("Session disqualified. Try again.");
        // You might want to perform some action here, like updating the server about the disqualification
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleBeforeUnload);
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", handleBeforeUnload);
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
    };
  }, [attemptCount]); // Rerun the effect if attemptCount changes

  return <div>Test content</div>;
};

export default TestComponentWithTabDetection;
```

the above code only give the alert not restrict the user
please rewrite the logic if you know